# Необходимо передать строку из активити в фрагмент

Tags: java, android-studio

Не получается передать строку из активити в фрагмент. Я новичек и в ответах по этой теме запуталась. Кто-то пишет надо так делать, кто-то по другому. Есть фрагмент, в нем активити и из этого активити необходимо "транслировать" данные в фрагмент. Помогите, пожалуйста

**Fragment:**

```
public class Home extends Fragment {

     public static Home newInstance() {
        Home fragment = new Home();
        return fragment;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, container, false);

    }
}
```

**Activity:**

```
public class SettingBD extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener{

    /* @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting_bd);
    }*/


    /*********************************************************************/

    Button btnSave, btnLoad;
    EditText etText, etText2, etText3;
    SharedPreferences sPref, sPref2, sPref3;

    final String SAVED_TEXT_BD = "saved_textBD";  ---- ЭТО ЗНАЧЕНИЕ НЕОБХОДИМО ТРАНСЛИРОВАТЬ
    final String SAVED_TEXT2_BD = "saved_textBD2";
    final String SAVED_TEXT3_BD = "saved_textBD3";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting_bd);
        /*Сохранение значений полей*/

        etText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        etText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        etText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBD);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnLoad = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loadBD);
        btnLoad.setOnClickListener(this);

        loadText();
    }    

 }
```

Comment: Для начала код добавьте

Comment: В приведенном выше коде я никак не вижу попытки передать значение

Comment: @РинаЧерная, в коде activity нету явного обращения к фрагменту. Также осложняет понимание отсутствие layout'ов в вопросе. Дополните, пожалуйста, вопрос недостающими материалами. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)